# Find installation directory of JDK in windows

Tags: windows, directory, java

I have an application which dynamically loads jvm.dll, therefore I need to know where the DLL resides. Currently I am trying standard locations like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk...\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll`. However this is quite tedious and error prone (due to version numbers etc.) and a more sophisticated solution would require some intelligence in my application to determine the correct path. In the worst case I end up asking the user to specify where jvm.dll resides.

On Mac OS X there is a method to find the Java Home directory using /usr/libexec/java_home, on Linux I am mostly fine with simply finding out where `javac` resides and following symlinks. Is there a similarily simple and sufficient method to find the location of a JDK without try-and-error, searching the whole filesystem, or asking the user?

This question is not about configuring my system such that javac is in my path or anything like that. I want to find, programmatically, the location of a JDK (or JRE for that matter) in a typical misconfigured windows system with screwed path variables and poor directory structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows 7, there is a DOS command that gets you the installation directory of java on the system. Try the below command.

```
where java
```

Comment: At least on my system java is installed in C:\Windows\System32, and jvm.dll is *not* there. This does not solve my problem, i.e. finding the JDK/JRE installation directory where the libraries and header files are.

Comment: I have windows 7 installed and where java when executed on my system it shows both the java in System32 as well as my jdk installation. I cant say for sure what the other Windows version shows when the same command is executed.

Comment: Ha! Thank you very much for the hint to the where utility! While initially it did not what I wanted I discovered the /R flag, to search the filesystem recursively. ALthough this is "searching the whole filesystem" it is good enough for me :-)